# When exactly is the autoloader called?

Tags: php, autoloader

I have an autoloader that is registered using `spl_autoload_register()`:

```
class MyAutoLoader{
   public function __construct(){
       spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loader'));
   }

   public function loader($className){
       var_dump($className);
   }
}

$al = new MyAutoLoader(); //Register the autoloader
```

From the `var_dump()`, the autoloader seems to be called on lots of things, things that are data to be inserted into a database, parameterized SQL queries and what not:

```
string 'name' (length=4)

string 'a:2:{s:5:"label";s:4:"Name";s:8:"required";b:1;}' (length=48)

string 'en_US' (length=5)

string 'object' (length=6)

string 'name = ?' (length=8)
```

These things will never be classes so should never be loaded using `new` or `class_exists()`, etc.

**Under what circumstances/function calls are autoloaders called?** I would like to put a stop to autoloading "classNames" that are not classes from being called, because each `$className` is checked using `file_exist()`, and having these data strings checked is pretty inefficient.

---

**Problem resolved.** I first did a back trace as suggested by Brad and dumped the traces to a file (just add a small snippet that opens a file and appends to it).

Obviously, the trace was very big, but I picked the simplest one I could find. Incidentally, that trace happened to be one that called a database (ORM) wrapper I have written to wrap around the awesome [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com) ORM library. The results from me dumping `$className` also validates that, because those strings are data are going into or coming out of the database.

Having said that, I have a `__call()` that intercepts methods to my database wrapper, does some processing, pass it to RedBean, process the result, and then sends it back to the caller.

**Problem: During the processing, I am making calls to [is_subclass_of()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-subclass-of.php) and [instanceof](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php), which will obviously ask the autoloader to try and load the class (since we don't have any class called `name =?` loaded, nor does it exist).**

The solution was to actually make sure we have an `object` before calling `is_subclass_of()` and `instanceof`: `if(is_object($someproperty) && is_subclass_of($someproperty))`.

If `$someproperty` is not an object, the `if` immediately short-circuits and `instanceof` and `is_subclass_of()` is never called, which means the call to the autoloader is never made.

As mentioned by brad, having all sorts of things going to the autoloader to be included using `require_once` can be a huge security risk and at the same time, hitting the file system so many times using `file_exists()` is pretty inefficient too.

So, in conclusion, the autoloader is called every time you use `instanceof`, `is_subclass_of`, other class-type functions, class-exist functions and reflection methods, as Charles motioned in his answer.

**So, the moral of the story is that if you plan to use a class-type function, or any of the functions mentioned above on a variable of mixed type, check it first before passing it to the class-type function.**

Comment: Wow, sounds like something is really broken in your code.  Are you sure some code isn't getting injected anywhere?  Sounds like a real security problem.  Care to show us the callstack with those, and related code?

Comment: @brad: The code is part of a pretty big application. What's the best way to get it to dump the call stack?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php  Use that to narrow down the line where arbitrary strings are ending up in your autoloader.

Comment: Cheers :) I will dump some traces and then update my question :)

Comment: Problem resolved and the approach I took has been edited into my question. Charles' answer contains various links which will be helpful for those who were wonder when autoloaders are called as I did. :)

Comment: So what was the actual cause?  If it was remotely interesting, it may well be a better answer to this question than mine was...

Comment: @Charles: Actual cause was calling `is_subclass_of()` and `instanceof` on a variable that could hold mixed types (objects or strings), which results in the call to the autoloader. I believe your answer is the most suitable as my question is about **when** autoloaders are called, with the problem of strings being passed to the autoloader being an illustration/secondary concern. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Under what circumstances/function calls are autoloaders called?

I realize that this has ended up basically being a *secondary* question given the problems noted in the comments, but it's still worth answering.

Autoload functions registered through [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) (PHP 5.1+), or before PHP 8.0.0 (deprecated PHP 7.2.0) [`__autoload()`](http://php.net/function.autoload) function, are called when — and only when — PHP needs to access a class that has not been defined.

This is done *everywhere* with few exceptions, such as [`class_exists`](http://php.net/class_exists), which has an argument that tell PHP not to call any autoloaders, being true by default triggering the autoloader, and can set to false to not to (second argument of class_exists()).

The PHP manual has [a page dedicated to autoloading](http://php.net/language.oop5.autoload).  I recommend reviewing it if there's any confusion.

Comment: Yeah, it's very important to notice that the default arguments for `class_exists()` will try to autoload the requested class and load it on success.

Comment: It's perhaps worth to comment that for both sides of `instanceof` the autoloader is **never** called (in regard to _"This is done _ everywhere _ with few exceptions"_ in the answer - mind the verbosity of the question thought) - at least if the right-hand side is a non-existent class-name (https://3v4l.org/YaaY0).

Comment: better: https://3v4l.org/ItjJf#v510

Answer (score 0):

You can use `debug_backtrace` or `debug_print_backtrace` to find out where exactly the auto-loader function is being called.

Technically it should only be called by PHP when a script references a class name that does not exist.